# Validation Attribute that takes a function as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have a few functions that validate an object based on multiple properties, I'd like to make a `ValidationAttribute` that accepts a function to run. IE:

```
[GenericValidationAttribute(NameIsValid)]
public class Person
{
     public string LastName {get;set;}

     public string NonIndividualName {get;set;}

     // At least one required.
     public bool NameIsValid()
     {
          return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LastName) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.NonIndividualName);
     }
}
```

What would GenericValidationAttribute look like? Maybe make NameIsValid static and accept a Person as a parameter and something like this?

```
class GenericValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Func<Person, bool> Delegate {get;set;}
    public GenericValidaitonAttribute (Func<Person, bool> delegate)
    {
         this.Delegate = delegate;
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
         return this.Delegate.Invoke(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly would be a purpose of that?